# Trying to get a count of a specifc value, does not match up to

Tags: sql, count, ms-access-2007

I have a table where I am trying to get a count of two placement values, `RA`  and `BB` by end_date from a "AAA table" using

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfPlacement, AAA.End_Date
  FROM AAA
 WHERE ((AAA.Placement.Value)="RA" 
    OR  (AAA.Placement.Value)="RB")
 GROUP BY AAA.End_Date;
```

The problem is that you can enter multiple values in the placement field. The query is double counting if the entry has both `RA` and `RB`, and I only want it counted once.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do a subquery so that you can establish your dataset, group all your records so there is no duplication and then count the remaining.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfPlacement
from     (
SELECT AAA.End_Date
FROM AAA
WHERE (((AAA.Placement.Value)="RA" Or (AAA.Placement.Value)="RB"))
GROUP BY AAA.End_Date;
)
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.  This might sound stupid (sorry, new to this) but do I have to make edits to the code you wrote?

Comment: Try it now... sorry I had a typo. I edited the code above. Basically all I did was wrap your statement in another statement and moved the count on the outside. So it does the logic first and then counts afterwords.

Comment: It runs, but I was trying to count the number of placements in a given time period (sorted by end date) and the sql statement only gives me a  a single total now. It's still giving me the same wrong number, but thank you

Comment: Try putting another AAA.End_Date on the outside query as well. Then you will maintain your group by but only count the unique rows.

Comment: This gives me the error "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "End_Date" as part of an aggregate function

Comment: Whenever you aggregate something like a count or a sum, you need to do a group by on whatever you plan to hold steady. So if you add a SELECT Count(*) as Count of Placement, End_Date at the beginning of the outer query, you'll also need to add a GROUP BY End_Date at the end after the Closing parens ).

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses and sorry for my delay.  This is a side project at work that isnt really urgent.  I'm still getting the double count but ohwell...It'll be solved eventually

thanks again!